# Split only upto 5 comma appear in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to split the below input strings up to the 5th comma. But I need the strings with comma also like in output. I tried

> (?<=\G\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+)

using regex. But it removes the comma in the 5th position.

```
String data = "12,23,34,45,56,78,9,";
String[] array = data.split("(?<=\\G\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+)"); //Magic :) 
// to reveal magic see explanation below answer
for(String s : array){
    System.out.println(s); //output = [12,23,34,45,56][78,9,]
}
```

Can someone try to give the solution which i expected in below output?

```
input string[] = 12,23,34,45,56,78,9,`enter code here`
output = [12,23,34,45,56,][78,9,]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can we assume there will always be more than 5 commas?

Comment: Yes.I want to split the strings on 5th comma(Always) including comma's.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the regular expression:

```
(?<=^\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+,)
```

---

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("(?<=^\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "12,23,34,45,56,78,9,";
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        REGEX_PATTERN.split(input)
    )); // prints "[12,23,34,45,56,, 78,9,]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the `split()` method, you could try to match with this pattern:

```
\\G((?:\\d+,?){5}|(?:\\d+,?)+)
```

Answer (score 0):

or this

```
(\d+,){5}(\d+,)*
```

explained

(\d+,){5}...match 'digit(s),' 5 times

(\d+,)*...match remaining portion